# Decision Warehouse "DataSource is not ready" for Business Rules Service on Bluemix

Tags: business-rules, ibm-cloud

I see the message "DataSource is not ready" in the Decision Warehouse tab of the Rule Execution Server console of the Business Rules Service. How should I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the Business Rules service on Bluemix does not use the Decision Warehouse for tracing rule execution, so this message can be safely ignored.